# Laws regarding or laws relating to?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

Is it right to say "Laws regarding estate property " or "laws relating to estate property"? Is there any diferense between this two phrases and which one is more official?

Comment: The mean the same, and neither is the more official.

Answer (score 1):

Both the prepositions have the same meaning, hence they can be used interchangeably. However, regarding is somewhat formal.

Comment: "regarding" isn't especially formal in American English. It is used in a wide variety of texts and contexts.